# CSS/HTML - Displaying products with responsive layout

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

I have an assignment to display products in specific way that needs to be responsive as well,
this is what I need to achieve:

[image: Table rows listing products information and prices]

In your opinion and experience, in order to achieve that what method will you use?
Bunch of divs? table? ul/li?

I need little bit of direction before I'll start encoding the image. and I'm looking
for the most efficient way for the responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way can only be done using bootstrap. A starter guide is found on the following site

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Just load the libraries in you project at the appropriate places and apply the classes to your tags to get the most responsive design you want.